# CodeIgniter Application Within an Existing Site

Tags: codeigniter

Our corporate website already is in place written in "long-hand" PHP. Since we plan to rebuild the site some time in 2011, I don't want to recode it in CodeIgniter (MVC) until we begin the redesign.

However, there are some additions we are making now (i.e., a newsroom/rss feed, a jobs post, etc) that I could add to the site as "modules" until the new design is created in CodeIgniter.

My question -- can I place a CI2 "application" in a folder at the root of my existing site and create my modules in CodeIgniter. For example, a stand-alone CI2 site named news would live in a folder at the root and would be called like www.company.com/news?

Thanks in advance for your insight,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question -- can I place a CI2
>   "application" in a folder at the root
>   of my existing site and create my
>   modules in CodeIgniter. For example, a
>   stand-alone CI2 site named news would
>   live in a folder at the root and would
>   be called like www.company.com/news?

Yes you can...

anything else? ;)

All joking aside, you could probably stick it into something like `/ci/` and use `.htaccess` to make URL rewriting, and point your sites `/news` --> `/ci/news/`etc;

That way you have 1 single CI instance, and you just point links to the instance:

```
/news => /ci/news/view/
/form => /ci/form/process/1
```

etc; number of ways to do it.

Comment: @jgravois, that should most likely be a *new* question on SO ;)